# Get a value from a formula

Tags: java

I was trying a formula in java to get until th value of 'g' is exactly 1 but i have error "java.lang.NullPointerException" in a specific line. Please help.

Here is my code :

```
int k1; //input from user
int j,g;
int[] f;

for (j = 1; j < 224; j++) {                         
   f[j] = (1 +(224*j)) / k1; //java.lang.NullPointerException is here
   g = (k1*f[j]) % 224; 
      if (g==1) {   
          break;
      }
}
```

Comment: Is the value entered == 0?

Comment: `k1` is declared, but not initialized

Comment: its obvious you dont have `k1` right ?

Comment: He mentioned `k1` is user input

Answer (score 2):

You haven't initialized any of those variables (`k1`, `j`, `g` and `f`). Though the `int`s might be 0 by default, the array being uninitialized should be giving you the NPE. So initialize it by writing:

```
int[] f = new int[SIZE];
```

where `SIZE` is the size you want to have for the array.

Answer (score 1):

you have not initialized int[] f array.
so its null

use it after initilaizing

```
int[] f = new int[224];
```

so your program should be like below

```
 k1; //input from user
int j,g;
int[] f = new int[224];

for (j = 1; j < 224; j++) {                         
   f[j] = (1 +(224*j)) / k1; //java.lang.NullPointerException is here
   g = (k1*f[j]) % 224; 
      if (g==1) {   
          break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your variables first - f is capable of holding an int array, but it doesn't at this point.
Since k1, j and g are so called primitives, their initial value (0) is valid.

```
int k1; //input from user
int j,g;
int[] f = new int[224]; // 224 is the number of items the array should hold

for (j = 1; j < 224; j++) {                         
   f[j] = (1 +(224*j)) / k1; //java.lang.NullPointerException is here
   g = (k1*f[j]) % 224; 
      if (g==1) {   
          break;
  }
}
```

Try to set a breakpoint in your IDE at the line the exception is thrown. If you examine your variables at this point, you should easily spot your problem yourself.